# Problems with file.path with csv import via sidekiq on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I am using a background job in order to import user data from a csv file into my datase. First I did this "hard" in my User model by simply calling a method in my User model and by passing the file path which is transmitted via a form `file_field`:

```
User.import_csv(params[:file].path)
```

Worked well locally and on production (heroku).

Now when it comes to huge CSV files, I understood that I need a job to perform this import in the background. I am familiar with redis and sidekiq so the job was built quickly.

```
CsvImportJob.perform_async(URI.parse(params[:file].path))
```

and in my worker:

```
def perform(file_path)

  User.import_csv(file_path)

end
```

Well, that also works perfect locally but as soon as I hit this on production, I see the following error in my log:

```
» 10 Aug 2015 13:56:26.596 2015-08-10 11:56:25.987726+00:00 app worker.1 - - 3 TID-oqvt6v1d4 ERROR: Actor crashed!
» 10 Aug 2015 13:56:26.596 2015-08-10 11:56:25.987728+00:00 app worker.1 - - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/RackMultipart20150810-6-14u804c.csv
» 10 Aug 2015 13:56:26.596 2015-08-10 11:56:25.987730+00:00 app worker.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1256:in `initialize'
```

This is meant to be the `file_path` variable.
Somehow heroku is not able to find the file when I pass it to a sidekiq job. When I do this without sidekiq, it works.

I don't really know how to tackle this issue so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience, you can look at a similar project of mine at https://github.com/coderaven/datatable-exercise/tree/parallel_processing

(Basically just focus on object_record.rb model and the jobs: import_csv_job.rb and process_csv_job.rb)

**The error:** Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen 
If you said that this works on heroku then probably that means that the path you are getting this is valid (in your example you are using the /tmp/ path)

**So here's 2 probable problems and their solution:**

**1.) You have saved an unknown to Heroku path (or inaccessible path) which cannot be access or opened by the application when it is running.** Since, when handling the import csv without sidekiq - the file you uploaded are save temporarily in-memory until you finish processing the csv - However, in a job scheduler (or sidekiq) the path should not be in memory and should be an existing path that is accessible to the app.

Solution: Save the file to a storage somewhere (heroku has an ephemeral filesystem so you cannot save files via the running web-app) to work this around, you have to use an Amazon S3 like service (you can also use Google Drive like what I did) to save your files there and then give the path to your sidekiq worker - so it can access and process it later.

2.) If the paths are correct and the files are save or processed correctly then from my experience **it could have been that you are using File.open instead of the open-uri's open method.** File.open does not accept remote files, you need to require open-uri on your worker and then use the open method to work around remote files.

ex.

```
require 'open-uri'

class ProcessCsvJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(csv_path)
    csv_file = open(csv_path,'rb:UTF-8')

    SmarterCSV.process(csv_file) do |array|
        .... code here for processing ...
    end
  end

end
```

I'm fully aware this question is already past almost a year, so if you have solved this or this answer worked then it could also help serve as a documentation archive for those who will probably experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a file object to the `perform` method.

The fix is to massage the data beforehand and pass in the parameters you need directly.

Something like...

```
def import_csv(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    new_user = { email: row[0], password: row[1] }
    CsvImportJob.perform_async(new_user)
  end
end
```

Note: you'd call `CsvImportJob.perform_later` for Sidekiq with ActiveJob and Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because on production/staging and sidekiq run on different servers. 
Use my solution: upload csv to google cloud storage

```
class Services::Downloader
  require 'fog'
  StorageCredentials = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/g.yml")[Rails.env]


  def self.download(file_name, local_path)
    storage = Fog::Storage.new(
        provider: "Google",
        google_storage_access_key_id: StorageCredentials['key_id'],
        google_storage_secret_access_key: StorageCredentials['access_key'])
    storage.get_bucket(StorageCredentials['bucket'])
    f = File.open(local_path)
    storage.put_object(StorageCredentials['bucket'], file_name, f)
    storage.get_object_https_url(StorageCredentials['bucket'], file_name, Time.now.to_f + 24.hours)
  end
end
```

Class User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  require 'csv'
  require 'open-uri'


  def self.import_data(file)
    load_file =  open(file)
    data = CSV.read(load_file, { encoding: "UTF-8", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all})
...
```

Worker

```
class ImportWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'workers', retry: 0

  def perform(filename)

    User.import_data(filename)
  end
end
```

and code for start worker

```
--
path = Services::Downloader.download(zip.name, zip.path)
      ImportWorker.perform_async(path)
```